# How to stop records moving into recyclebin once deleted?

Tags: recycle-bin

I want the records created for my custom object to get deleted permanently when deleted, without moving it into the recycle bin.how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Database.emptyRecycleBin(sObject)](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_emptyRecycleBin_2) method or the [other variants in the Database class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database.htm) such as [Database.emptyRecycleBin(sObject[])](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_emptyRecycleBin_3)

For example, to permanently delete a contact with Id of '003i000000O4xYZ' in the recycle bin:

```
Contact c = new Contact(Id = '003i000000O4XyZ');
Database.emptyRecycleBin(c);
```

Also note that there is a couple of other variants of this method. One which takes a list of Id's as well.

You can create following trigger on your object to delete records

```
trigger tgrDelete on Contact (after delete) {

 List<Contact> lstContact = Trigger.old;
 Database.emptyRecycleBin(lstContact);

}
```

Comment: Its not about a single record,I don't want any of the records related with that particular object to move into recycle bin..

Comment: You could write a trigger using this kind of code to permanently delete the records just deleted

Comment: there is no configuration option available for this in Salesforce so you have only two option. 

1. Write a batch class which will run daily in your org and permanently delete records with my code. (This option is better because you can define multiple objects.)
2. Write a trigger on that particular object to permanently delete.

Comment: How can I do it using trigger?can you give me simple example?

Comment: I have updated the code please check